# GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync Hangs

Tags: c#, asp.net, youtube, google-api-dotnet-client

Our website needs to upload videos to youtube from the code behind (asp.net mvc application). I'm trying to get the google credentials, but when i call the AuthorizeAsync, the application just hangs. I've looked all over for a solution and none seem to help out.  I've already searched for the obvious on google and stack overflow. most of what i found mentioned that the application might not have access the the appdata folder, so i tried changing the folder to be in the c drive, d drive and in the actual inetpub location. i tested and found i was able to have the application write to those locations.

to be more specific, the user is our admin, customers upload videos to us, and the admin approves them. when the admin approves them, it is posted on our youtube account. the admin should not have to do anything but click the approve button.

To make this an actual question, what can i do to get past the AuthorizeAsync? Let me know if you need more info

```
        UserCredential credential;
        GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "YouTube.Auth.Store";
        using (var stream = new FileStream(CredentialsPath, FileMode.Open,
                             FileAccess.Read))
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows an application to upload files to the
                // authenticated user's YouTube channel, but doesn't allow other types of access.
                new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")
            ).Result;
        }
```

Comment: Did you try to use async, like suggested here: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web_applications

Comment: I have not solved this yet, but in case anybody wants to know, i think i've found a solution here: https://anilanar.wordpress.com/2013/07/19/upload-youtube-videos-for-single-account-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: Google, in spite of being top Internet company, sucks at providing errors for developers. I hate using its client libraries.

Comment: AuthorizeAsync also hung for me and after many trial and error steps found that the problem was path in 'new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")' was wrong on the server where it was running.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Found a way to get passed this.

I used GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow instead. this is what it turned out to look like:

```
        ClientSecrets secrets = new ClientSecrets()
        {
            ClientId = CLIENT_ID,
            ClientSecret = CLIENT_SECRET
        };

        var token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = REFRESH_TOKEN }; 
        var credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
            new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer 
            {
                ClientSecrets = secrets
            }), 
            "user", 
            token);

        var service = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credentials,
            ApplicationName = "TestProject"
        });
```

Comment: This is what I was finally able to do to get it to work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607989/upload-video-to-youtube-with-mvc-application-all-code-behind

Comment: Do you literally use the string "user" as the argument to GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(), or do you use some Google username?

Comment: What is `REFRESH_TOKEN`?

Comment: @Rick that's what I use for my `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()` call.  They look similar so I'm guessing the answer to your question is "yes".

Comment: @Rick - yes, you have literally use string "user" - that comes from Google API sample code: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video

Comment: thank you @avs099, i never replied with the answer because it was a while ago when i did this so i couldn't remember

Comment: @xr280xr `REFRESH_TOKEN` is a permanent token which you can later exchange for the access token to be used by your server-side app (as that's the context here). You can play with it in Google OAuth Playground https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/. Workflow here should be as follows: (i) You register new project in Google Console https://console.developers.google.com/ and generate "Other" credentials. That will give you clientId and clientSecret. (ii) you use `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync` once to authorize the app and get `REFRESH_TOKEN` (iii) you hardcode it in code :)

Comment: @avs099 That works. But I have a point here that it is for only one user, once the credentials  saved and access token generated it's same. In my web application we have several users and I want to authorize all of them so that they can use their own google account?

Comment: getting a scope error with this method while using analytics reporting api. tried to add scopes by hand but failed

Comment: where can i add callback URL in the? Please help

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to break out if this, for example using a timeout, because the `AuthorizeAsync` method has the implementation of a `CancellationToken`.

- Create a `TokenSource` to obtain the Token itself.
- Set the Cancellation of the TokenSource to i.e. 20 Seconds
- Extract the token to pass to the `AuthorizeAsync` method.

---

```
public async void RunAsync()
{
    UserCredential credential;
    var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
    CancellationToken ct = cts.Token;

    credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
    "user",
    ct
    );

    if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) return;

    // do more stuff when came back authorized.
}
```

Now, after 20 seconds, when the `AuthorizeAsync` was **not** completed, the caller of this method `RunAsync` will receive an Exception.

```
try
{
    await RunAsync();
}
catch(Exception)
{
     // "Timeout" of the RunAsync(); 
}
```

Comment: I've been looking for this answer for too long. Thank you.

It still keeps the opened browser, but that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

The following code lets you use your google drive api credentials to request login information from the user, and download the file to your server to perform some request:

```
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Web
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports Google
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Web
Imports Google.Apis.Services

'for drive
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2
Imports Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data
Imports Google.Apis.Util.Store
'for AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl
Imports Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests
Imports System.Drawing

Public Class _Default
    Inherits Page

    Private redirect_uri As String = ""
    Private client_id As String = ""
    Private client_secret As String = ""
    Private service As DriveService

    'Application logic should manage users authentication. 
    'This sample works with only one user. You can change it by retrieving
    'data from the session.
    'You use the word user because you are authorized by the user to access
    'their drive contents.
Private UserId As String = "user" 

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Dim SCOPES As String() = New [String]() {"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.install"}
    Dim flow As GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
    'use extended class to create google authorization code flow
    'use custom own datastore
    flow = New ForceOfflineGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(New GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer() With {
    .DataStore = New FileDataStore("D:\inetpub\wwwroot\go\filedatastore", True),
    .ClientSecrets = New ClientSecrets() With {
        .ClientId = client_id,
        .ClientSecret = client_secret
    },
    .Scopes = SCOPES
})

    Dim uri = Request.Url.ToString()
    Dim redirecturi As String = redirect_uri
    Dim code = Request("code")
    If code IsNot Nothing Then
        output.Text &= "<br />Code: " & code & "<br />"
        output.Text &= "<br />UserID: " & UserId & "<br />"
        output.Text &= "<br />URI: " & uri & "<br />"
        output.Text &= "<br />RedirectURI: " & redirecturi & "<br />"
        output.Text &= "<br />uri-substring-thing: " & uri.Substring(0, uri.IndexOf("?")) & "<br />"
        Dim token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(UserId, code, redirecturi, CancellationToken.None).Result

        ' Extract the right state.
        Dim oauthState = AuthWebUtility.ExtracRedirectFromState(flow.DataStore, UserId, Request("state")).Result
        Response.Redirect(oauthState)
    Else

        Dim result = New AuthorizationCodeWebApp(flow, redirecturi, uri).AuthorizeAsync(UserId, CancellationToken.None).Result

        If result.RedirectUri IsNot Nothing Then
            ' Redirect the user to the authorization server.
            Response.Redirect(result.RedirectUri)
        Else
            ' The data store contains the user credential, so the user has been already authenticated.


            service = New DriveService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
            .HttpClientInitializer = result.Credential,
            .ApplicationName = "Drive API Sample"
        })
        End If
    End If

End Sub

''' <summary>
''' Download a file
''' Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get
''' </summary>
''' <param name="_service">a Valid authenticated DriveService</param>
''' <param name="_fileResource">File resource of the file to download</param>
''' <param name="_saveTo">location of where to save the file including the file name to save it as.</param>
''' <returns></returns>
Public Shared Function downloadFile(_service As DriveService, _fileResource As Data.File, _saveTo As String) As [Boolean]

    If Not [String].IsNullOrEmpty(_fileResource.DownloadUrl) Then
        Try
            Dim x = _service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(_fileResource.DownloadUrl)
            Dim arrBytes As Byte() = x.Result
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_saveTo, arrBytes)
            Return True
        Catch e As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message)
            Return False
        End Try
    Else
        ' The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
        Return False
    End If
End Function

Public Async Function GetFile(IncomingFileID As String) As Tasks.Task
    Try
        Dim request As FilesResource.GetRequest = service.Files.Get(IncomingFileID)
        Dim response As Data.File = Await request.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None)
        downloadFile(service, response, "D:/inetpub/wwwroot/go/" & Guid.NewGuid.ToString)

    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim str As String = "<br />" & ex.ToString()
        str = str.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + "<br/>")
        str = str.Replace("  ", " &nbsp;")
        output.Text &= String.Format("<font color=""red"">{0}</font>", str)
    End Try
End Function


'''<summary>Gets the File Lists of the user.</summary>
Public Async Function FetchFilelists() As System.Threading.Tasks.Task
    Try
        ' Get all files of the user asynchronously.
        Dim request As FilesResource.ListRequest = service.Files.List()

        'get only my files
        request.Q = "mimeType contains 'image/'"

        Dim response As FileList = Await request.ExecuteAsync()

        ShowFilelists(response)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Dim str = ex.ToString()
        str = str.Replace(Environment.NewLine, Environment.NewLine + "<br/>")
        str = str.Replace("  ", " &nbsp;")
        output.Text = String.Format("<font color=""red"">{0}</font>", str)
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub ShowFilelists(response As FileList)
    If response.Items Is Nothing Then
        output.Text &= "You have no files!<br/>"
        Return
    End If

    output.Text &= "Showing files...<br/>"
    Dim ctr As Integer = 0
    For Each file As Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.File In response.Items
        ctr += 1
        Dim listPanel As New Panel() With {
            .BorderWidth = Unit.Pixel(1),
            .BorderColor = Color.Black
        }
        listPanel.Controls.Add(New Label() With {
            .Text = file.Title + "--" + file.MimeType
                })
        listPanel.Controls.Add(New Label() With {
            .Text = "<hr/>"
            })


        If file.MimeType.ToString().Contains("folder") = False Then
            listPanel.Controls.Add(New HyperLink() With {
            .Text = "Download",
            .NavigateUrl = file.WebContentLink
        })

            listPanel.Controls.Add(New Button() With {
                                   .Text = "Use This Image", .OnClientClick = "document.getElementById('currentImageId').value = '" & file.Id & "';return false;"})

        End If
        lists.Controls.Add(listPanel)
    Next

    output.Text &= "Total Files: " & ctr.ToString
End Sub



Protected Async Sub listButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles listbutton.Click
    Await FetchFilelists()
End Sub

Protected Async Sub DownloadImageButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DownloadImageButton.Click
    Dim idToUse As String = Page.Request.Form(currentImageId.UniqueID)

    output.Text &= "<br />Attempting to download id: " & idToUse & "<br />"
    Await GetFile(idToUse)
    output.Text &= "<br />Download Completed<br />"
End Sub

'overwrite. force offline.
Friend Class ForceOfflineGoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
    Inherits GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
    'source: //gotoanswer.stanford.edu/google_analytics_oauth_with_accesstype__offline_in_c-4478263/

    Public Sub New(initializer As GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer)
        MyBase.New(initializer)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(redirectUri As String) As AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl
        Dim ss = New Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(New Uri(AuthorizationServerUrl))
        ss.AccessType = "offline"
        ss.ApprovalPrompt = "force"
        ss.ClientId = ClientSecrets.ClientId
        ss.Scope = String.Join(" ", Scopes)
        ss.RedirectUri = redirectUri
        Return ss
    End Function
End Class


End Class
```

Here's the WebForm .aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb"     Inherits="PictureMyCard._Default" Async="True" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" 
runat="server">


<div>
    <asp:Button ID="listbutton" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="list" />
<asp:Label id="output" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="..." ></asp:Label>
</div>
    <asp:Label ID="lists" ClientIDMode="Static" Text="..." runat="server"></asp:Label>
<hr />

<asp:HiddenField ClientIDMode="Static" ID="currentImageId" runat="server" />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="DownloadImageButton" ClientIDMode="Static"  Text="Download Image to server" />
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Folder = "YouTube.Auth.Store";
```

This line will generate a access token in YouTube.Auth.Store/xxx, and you need to right click ***this file -> properties -> Copy to Output Directory -> Copy always*** in visual studio

it works for me.